# Using super with class method in python

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, super

I am trying to understand how to make this work. I want instantiate the parent class using a class method. This code gives me an error:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, a, b, c):
        return cls(a, b, c)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, p):
        super(Child, self).class_method(x, y, z)
        self.p = p

c = Child(1, 2, 3, 10)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)
```

I know the reason too. It because the `cls` variable holds the `Child` class. So when `cls(a, b, c)` is called, python tries to initialize the `Child` class with 4 arguments, `self`, `a`, `b`, `c`. But the `Child` class needs 5 arguments.
How do I achieve this functionality? I understand that we should not use factory methods unless absolutely necessary. Assume it's necessary.

Comment: That's the point, I want to call the class method. In this case, it's doing nothing, but it can do some transformations on the input and pass it to the __init__ method as well

Comment: I don't think your class method does what you think it does. It's not modifying the current object, but simply returning a newly instantiated one. You can call the class method by using "Base.class_method(x, y, z)", but it's pretty useless unless you actually use its result.

Comment: I see, my approach is wrong. But how do I instantiate a super class using a class method? That's my main question

Answer (score 0):

You actually should not use `@classmethod` in this particular instance
`@staticmethod` is a better solution

as you noticed, class `Child` is passed into `Base.do` method.
but if you want to always work with class `Base`, simply make the static method like so

```
class Base:
    @staticmethod
    def do(a, b, c):
        return Base(a, b, c)
```

using `@staticmethod` is better because in class `Base`'s `do` method you want to always use that same class and not other classes

this can be a slight problem when, let's say, renaming class but it can be dealt with using IDLE's (or almost any other text editor) replace function (Edit > Replce (Ctrl + H))

Comment: class Base:
    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a, b, c):
        return cls(a, b, c)

is much safer if someone ever wants make a subclass.

Answer (score -1):

What you should do in this exact example is:

```py
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, a, b, c):
        return cls(a, b, c)

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, p):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)
        self.p = p

c = Child(1, 2, 3, 10)
```

However, assuming you do want to call a class method, you should never call a class method in `__init__` (at least one that behaves like a factory). Init happens *after* the class is instantiated. So instead you'd need to override `__new__`. And, you need to be able to fully construct the class with the original signature to use the original class method, so you need to override the class method in your subclass too.